# CMake : how to use bash command in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: bash, cmake

I'm wondering how I can use bash command in CMakeLists.txt. What I want is to get the number of processor retrieved using :

```
export variable=`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`
```

and set NB_PROCESSOR to variable using something like :

```
SET (NB_PROCESSOR variable)
```

So my question is how can I use the getconf command in CMakeLists.txt and how can I use the result (stored in variable) in CMake SET command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to do the trick, and saves the "set" too.

```
execute_process(COMMAND getconf  _NPROCESSORS_ONLN
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE NB_PROCESSOR)
```

Comment: with this, i see the result of the command during "cmake ." but if I have "#cmakedefine NB_PROCESSOR ${NB_PROCESSOR}" to my config.h.in, I'll get "#undef NB_PROCESSOR" instead of "#define NB_PROCESSOR value". Any clue?

Comment: I messed up - it should be OUTPUT_ not RESULT_VARIABLE. The former stores the output from the program, the latter the result ($? in bash-speak)

Comment: already tried and seems not to work, I think the result may be considered as a string and I want a int. Still trying to find a solution :)

Comment: oups, I was wrong about saying I tried using the output_var, it works! thanks!

Comment: It might be important to remove the trailing whitespaces from the output of getconf (simply append `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` in the execute process cmake command). Using `NB_PROCESSOR` in a precompiler definition may be erroneous otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

Use the EXEC_PROGRAM command and then use the CACHE option of the SET 
command to save the output to a variable like GTK_PKG_FLAGS.  Then use 
the SET command to add the value.  Something like this:

```
IF(NOT GTK_PKG_FLAGS)
   EXEC_PROGRAM(pkg-config ARGS --cflags --libs gtkmm
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GTK_PKG_FLAGS)
   SET(GTK_PKG_FLAGS "${GTK_PKG_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "GTK Flags")
ENDIF(NOT GTK_PKG_FLAGS)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GTK_PKG_FLAGS}")
```

Links: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2005-January/006051.html